# CalendarView Jetpack Compose Buttons Are Not Displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-datepicker

I have the following requirement: the user can enter a name in the first text field of a dialog, but when the user clicks on the second (disabled) text field a DatePicker is supposed to open.

[image]

I've implemented a Date Picker following some instructions on SO, but I've run into a weird UI bug with the buttons below the CalendarView.

This is my Composable for the Date Picker including a CustomCalendarView:

```
@Composable
fun JourneyDatePicker(
    isVisible: Boolean = false,
    date: Long?,
    onDateSelected: (Long) -> Unit,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit
) {
    var selectedDate by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            when {
                date != null && date > 0L -> date
                else -> DateTime.now().millis
            }
        )
    }

    if (isVisible) Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        properties = DialogProperties()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .background(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp)
                )
        ) {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 72.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Datum auswählen"
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))
                Text(
                    text = DateTime().withMillis(selectedDate).toString(DateTimeFormat.longDate())
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
            }
            CustomCalendarView(
                date = selectedDate,
                onDateSelected = {
                    selectedDate = it
                }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.End)
                    .padding(bottom = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            ) {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedDate = DateTime.now().millis
                        onDismissRequest()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Cancel",
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        onDateSelected(selectedDate)
                        onDismissRequest()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "OK",
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomCalendarView(
    date: Long?,
    onDateSelected: (Long) -> Unit
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            CalendarView(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DatePickerCustom))
        },
        update = { view ->
            view.apply {
                date?.let { d ->
                    if (d > 0L) setDate(d) else DateTime.now().millis
                }
                setOnDateChangeListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    onDateSelected(
                        DateTime
                            .now()
                            .withMonthOfYear(month + 1)
                            .withYear(year)
                            .withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth)
                            .millis
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The issue is:

- when the dialog with the two input fields for name and date opens and I click on the Date field, the buttons of the DatePicker are displayed:

  [image]
- when the dialog opens and I edit the name and then click on the Date field, the buttons are not displayed:

  [image]

I've also cleared the focus using FocusManager just in case this is some issue with the keyboard but that didn't help either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  [Here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/be8015d88b060fb7df788df88c28acc9) is mine, and I haven't faced such issues. If you can reproduce it with my code, it may be platform related

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce it with your code. Buttons are not shown either. https://pasteboard.co/BzwShLFbGPr7.png

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else faces this issue, I finally figured out what the problem is.

It's basically an issue between the open keyboard and how the `Dialog()` Composable calculates the height of the dialog. Because the `Dialog()` Composable calculates the available height before the keyboard is fully closed, the calculated height is smaller than the actual available height for the Dialog.

So you can either:

- not use the `Dialog()` Composable in this case or
- use a tiny delay between closing the keyboard and opening the dialog (which works but I would **not** recommend it).

If you want to debug this issue, the following function in the `Dialog()` Composable is a good place to start:

```
override fun internalOnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem apart from finding out the reason? I have the same problem on a scrollable column with textfields. if I first open the calendar then it is ok.if I first focus on a textfield and then open the calendar then the cancel and ok buttons are not visible.

Comment: Yeah kind of. I solved it by not using the out-of-the-box Dialog() Composable and just building a custom one that looks like a dialog. Was the best solution at the time :)